# How do I apply a sliding window technique on images for multiple people detection?

Tags: matlab, svm, sliding-window

I am implementing HOG for people detecting and SVM Classifier has been trained.But I am not aware on how to use that pretrained classifier for detection using sliding window technique.Please someone guides me to build a sliding window technique for multiple people detection in Matlab.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect people within the sliding window?

Comment: Yes sir..I got my dataset classified as person and non person..now I want to detect the people in that classified image...for detection im using sliding window technique..

Answer (score 0):

The python tutorial over [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/) should give you an idea on how to implement this.

The basic idea is for each window, compute the hog descriptors (using opencv, for example) and then multiply element-wise the HOG descriptors with the trained SVM weights (They should be the same size). After multiplying, add the bias (which is another output from the SVM classifier) to the previous result. If the result is positive, it's a positive match, otherwise it's a negative match.

Note: the sliding window size is the same size as the training images.

So,

```
for each pixel in the image:
   get a sub-image of size of sliding window
   compute the HOG descriptors for this image
   product = hog * SVM_weights //element-wise multiplication
   response = product + bias
   if response > 0:
       print "match"
   else:
       print "no match"
```

Comment: Ok Sir but im implementing it using MATLAB ..can this same idea implemented using MATLAB?

Comment: Of course. Try and understand the logic of the sliding window technique and you should be able to implement it in matlab. Here's an example for HOG SVM in matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html